# Multi platform data protection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Question: what is the best way to secure data when developing a multi-platform .NET Core 1.1 application?

Let me explain what I mean: the application has a configuration file that contains a database connection password.

I want to do things the right way, which means that after reading the password for the very first time I would prefer to encrypt the string in the configuration file. Clearly, I need to use some kind of symmetric encryption with some kind of passphrase. With Windows I would use DPAPI and host identity to produce my passphrase (*after obfuscating it a bit of course*).

Linux does not have DPAPI... Is there a truly ***multiplatform*** way of achieving what I've described?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: it's preferred for the implementation code base to be the same not depending on the environment / host OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All the sensitive settings should be encrypted in the configuration file
2. The decryption keys should be stored in environment-variables

Then the application should decrypt the settings on the fly, when it needs those.

Comment: I like the environment variable approach. Will I need a single set of code to work with environment variables from .net core application for both Linux and Windows?

Comment: @PhilP. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() method should work.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more info on this solution involving storing keys as environment variables? I understand how the application would use the environment variables, but who and when does set up this env variable securely? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marius. That should be part of the deployment process. In case of an Azure App Service deployment you can use ARM templates to achieve that. Here is a blog post about it: https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/adding-environment-variables-to-an-arm-template-for-azure-app-services/

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a "truly multiplatform" way to invoke the native OS-level encryption primitives on every platform from a single implementation. I believe many vendors have to target the OS' APIs on a case-by-case basis.

This [CIA advice](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/files/NOD%20Cryptographic%20Requirements%20v1.1%20TOP%20SECRET.pdf) is probably good evidence to support that working around "doing it the hard way" and targeting every platform specifically, probably speaks to the risks involved with trying to find a shortcut:

> All tools must utilize Operating System (OS) provided cryptographic primitives where
>   available (e.g., Microsoft CryptoAPI-NG, OpenSSL, PolarSSL, GnuTLS, etc).